# Why does the Entity Framework Core NuGet package depend on ASP.NET and Websockets?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a normal class library (not a .NET Core/Standard library) that uses Entity Framework Core.

After installing it I noticed it seems to pull in a whole bunch of NuGet packages I absolutely shouldn't need to be depending on. My library has nothing to do with ASP.NET, and yet because I want to use EF, it appears I have to have dependencies on parts of ASP.NET.

[image]

Will EF Core run correctly if I remove these? I'm concerned that if my library *is used by* an ASP.NET application that these dependencies are going to cause problems.

It is the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` package that is causing ASP.NET to be installed. So it appears that if you need to use `Update-Database` etc, you must have a dependency on ASP.NET. This seems like a very poor idea.

[image]

Comment: EF Core [does not have Asp.Net listed as a dependency](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/).  Are you positive it was EF Core that added the dependencies to Asp.Net?

Comment: Yep. Make a new class library and install Entity Framework Core.

Comment: It is not EF Core that has added the AspNet Nuget packages, perhaps a Visual Studio project template has added those dependencies, what kind of project do you have going in Visual Studio?

Comment: "I have a normal class library (not a .NET Core/Standard library)"

Comment: Maybe that is why AspNet packages are added...because you have a .NET Framework class library, a .NET Standard Class library should get you a leaner amount of packages

Comment: I also do not know why your question just got marked down, wish people would provide feedback when they mark down a question

Comment: Or create a .NET Core Class library is probably what you want instead of Standard

Comment: I've only just realised that a .NET Core library is not the same thing as a .NET Standard library, despite Core implementing Standard. This confusion and lack of clarity from the .NET teams gets worse all the time.

Comment: Still no apparent solution for removing these pointless dependencies.

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7835 They should go away in 2.0 release